# Deep reinforcment learning generalization

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

I am interested in evaluating deep reinforcement models. How can we evaluate a model trained in a Reinforcement learning manner ? can we quantify the RL generalization ?

Answer (score 3):

> How can we evaluate a model trained in a Reinforcement learning
> manner ?

Evaluation of the performance of an RL model varies very widely depending on the task. For example, you could use the average reward as an evaluation metric, or if there's a reasonable "success condition", you could use that as the metric. In other situations you might use already established metrics of performance, (such as chess ELO).

> can we quantify the RL generalization ?

If you're generalizing from some environment E to a different environment E', then you could simply measure the performance on E', or the performance drop from E to E'.